# phpMyAdmin user table not in sync with site user list

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

The users in my phpMyAdmin user table don't tally with the user list in my Wordpress site.

I tried testing by creating a user in phpMyAdmin, the user doesn't appear in my Wordpress site. I also tried deleting a user from my Wordpress site, the user is still reflected in my phpMyAdmin user table.

**What could be the issue here? How do I solve this?**

Another thing is that I am intending to migrate the entire site to another server soon.

**If I duplicate the site and migrate it to the other server, will I duplicate this problem over to the new location?**

Comment: Looks like you are not watching to right database on phpmyadmin because you can't have a difference between db and admin. Except having a cache wrongly configured which cache the admin

Comment: I thought so at first, because I have never faced this issue before.

Comment: Look into wp-config.php for MySQL credentials and I'm pretty sure you will see they don't match credentials you use in phpmyadmin

Comment: Ok thanks I'll take a look there

Comment: In which database is the 'user' table you're manually adding users to: mysql, phpmyadmin, or wordpress?

Comment: I attempted adding users manually on both phpmyadmin and wordpress

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new user in phpMyAdmin from the "User accounts" tab, you're creating a MySQL user. The information for a MySQL user is stored in the mysql system database.

Wordpress follows the very standard practice of storing user accounts in a database, but not as explicit database users. So when your Wordpress installation is interacting with the database, it's doing it as a wordpress user, not as the individual users on your site. Usernames and passwords are stored in an application database, usually called wordpress, and as far as MySQL is concerned it's just another couple of bits of data being stored.

I believe your trouble comes from trying to manipulate the system database instead of the wordpress database. When adding, monitoring, or removing a user, you should be examining a table under the wordpress database (I think it's called users but don't have Wordpress handy to check). When you're adding a user through the phpMyAdmin User accounts tab, you're creating a MySQL system user; since MySQL and Wordpress don't share the same authentication tables you're not seeing the proper updates.

The simplest way to create a user is to use the provided Wordpress tools. The password stored must be hashed and stored in some secure means; without knowing what formula/function is used, you'll only manually be able to create new accounts that you can't match the password.

Hope that helps; it sounds like you're mentally combining the two different authentication means.